# Adding a burn feature to the contract

Tags: burn

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

interface IBEP20 {
//functions
  function name() external view returns (string memory);
  function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256);
  function getOwner() external view returns (address);
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view returns (uint256);
  function burn(address _owner, address _spender) external returns (uint256);


//events
  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
  event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}

/* This contract created by YazilimNedir.com */
contract YazilimNedir is IBEP20{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address private _ownerOfContract;
    string private _name = "Yaztoken";
    string private _symbol = "YZTKN";
    uint8 private _decimals = 4;
    uint256 private _totalSupply = 10000000000000;

    mapping(address=>uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint8 private _commissionPercent = 3;
    address private constant _commissionWallet = 0x792b262e797B77eD8d2eEcEF2Be4e540648f5c51;

    constructor()
    {
        _ownerOfContract = msg.sender;
        _balances[_ownerOfContract] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _ownerOfContract, _totalSupply);
    }

    function name() external view returns (string memory){
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory){
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8){
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256){
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256){
        return _balances[_owner];
    }

    function getOwner() external view returns (address){
        return _ownerOfContract;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
     
        function burn(address _to(0), address owner, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }



    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");

        if(_takeCommission(sender, recipient)){
            _transferWithCommission(sender, recipient, amount);
        } 
        else{
            _transferWOCommission(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        _approve(_from, msg.sender, _allowances[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _approve(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view returns (uint256){
        return _allowances[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function _transferWithCommission(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private
    {
         _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
         uint256 _fee = _calcCommission(amount, _commissionPercent);
         _balances[_commissionWallet] = _balances[_commissionWallet].add(_fee);
         _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount.sub(_fee));
         emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount.sub(_fee));
    }

    function _calcCommission(uint256 value, uint8 commissionPercent) private pure returns(uint256)
    {
        return value.mul(commissionPercent).div(100);
    }

    function _transferWOCommission(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private
    {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _takeCommission(address sender,address recipient) private pure returns(bool)
    {
        if(sender == _commissionWallet || recipient == _commissionWallet){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

}

library SafeMath {
    /**
     * @dev Returns the addition of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `+` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Addition cannot overflow.
     */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the subtraction of two unsigned integers, reverting with custom message on
     * overflow (when the result is negative).
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `-` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Subtraction cannot overflow.
     */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the multiplication of two unsigned integers, reverting on
     * overflow.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `*` operator.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - Multiplication cannot overflow.
     */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the integer division of two unsigned integers. Reverts with custom message on
     * division by zero. The result is rounded towards zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `/` operator. Note: this function uses a
     * `revert` opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity
     * uses an invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the remainder of dividing two unsigned integers. (unsigned integer modulo),
     * Reverts with custom message when dividing by zero.
     *
     * Counterpart to Solidity's `%` operator. This function uses a `revert`
     * opcode (which leaves remaining gas untouched) while Solidity uses an
     * invalid opcode to revert (consuming all remaining gas).
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - The divisor cannot be zero.
     */
    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}
```

Hello dear solidity experts. I added the burn feature to this contract. But I am getting error. I would be very grateful if you could point out my mistake and correct it. These are the codes I added.

```
        function burn(address _to(0), address owner, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
  function burn(address _owner, address _spender) external returns (uint256);
```

error: ypeError: Contract "YazilimNedir" should be marked as abstract.
--> token.sol:26:1:
|
26 | contract YazilimNedir is IBEP20{
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Missing implementation:
--> token.sol:17:3:
|
17 | function burn(address _owner, address _spender) external returns (uint256);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is intended, but you are using a very sketchy-looking contract that does not adhere to the ERC20 standard (or BEP20 for that matter) and that has a commission address hardcoded in there.

I would strongly advise not to use this code, but to get to the root of the problem:

your interface declares a function

```
  function burn(address _owner, address _spender) external returns (uint256);
```

Yet you have implemented (incorrectly) a function with different parameters.

```
function burn(address _to(0), address owner, uint256 _value) external returns (bool){
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

A function that implements an interface needs all functions to be implemented, otherwise it should be declared as abstract (meaning that it is declared as "non-complete" and that there are missing functions).

your interface should actually declare a function (following OpenZeppelin's ERC20Burnable extension)

```
  function burn(address from, uint256 amount) external;
```

With the code being something like:

```
function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public virtual {
        _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(amount);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);

        emit Transfer(from, address(0), amount);
    }
```

In fact, I wouldn't even use BEP20 (you probably won't be bridging to the Binance Chain and can still implement a `getOwner` function if you like) and simply use trusted code libraries, like [OpenZeppelin's ERC20Burnable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol)